# setDataSource(datasource) not coming for JdbcUserDetailsManager in spring?

Tags: spring-security, datasource, spring-boot

I am new to spring security and trying to implement spring security in my Spring Boot Application. I defined my DataBase details in application.properties and have added the following code in my Application.class

```
@Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
    private String databaseDriverClassName;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String datasourceUrl;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String databaseUsername;

    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    private String databasePassword;

    @Bean
    public DataSource datasource() {
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource ds = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(databaseDriverClassName);
        ds.setUrl(datasourceUrl);
        ds.setUsername(databaseUsername);
        ds.setPassword(databasePassword);

        return ds;
    }
```

Now in SecurityConfiguration class when i am trying to set the datasource, it is showing as error(method is not there for class  JdbcUserDetailsManager ) you can find the code below

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvcSecurity
    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  {

        @Autowired
        private DataSource datasource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            http
                    .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                    .permitAll();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
                throws Exception {

            JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
            userDetailsService.setDataSource(datasource);// here setDataSource() is not been identified     

PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        // this is where i want to use userDetailsService
        if(!userDetailsService.userExists("user")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
            User userDetails = new User("user", encoder.encode("password"), authorities);

            userDetailsService.createUser(userDetails);
        } 

    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue or suggest any alternative to set datasource.
Here is the POM.xml

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.10.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
           </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Please help.

Comment: Use `auth.userDetailsService(dataSource)` instead of creating a new instance of the `JdbcUserDetailsService`.

Comment: But auth.userDetailsService() takes JdbcUserDetailsManager object as parameter.

Comment: Sorry mixing things in my head, use `auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)` instead.

Comment: Please find the updated SecurityConfiguration, if i use auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource()  then how can i use  userExists()  method in if() condition

Comment: Don't. At least not there, that is configuration and not application logic. Use an `ApplicationListener` for that or simply use a sql script to insert the user (simply adding a `data.sql` in a Spring Boot application is enough).

Comment: That is why i want to use SpringSecurity, spring boot . Instead of writing sql script i want to use JdbcUserDetailsManager  as it contains all the sql logic for user creation , update etc..

Comment: Then just configure it and use an `ApplicationListener` to execute your logic. Don't mix the configuration and filling of the database.